# .NET Core: error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-standard

I recently moved from Visual Studio (Windows) to Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu Linux), and due to patchy beta .NET 5 support, I re-targeted from .NET 5 to .NET Standard 2.0 library projects (as I should have in the first place), and .NET 5 to .NET Core 3.1 on my executable projects. The transition seemed to go smoothly...

...but when I run the executable, I get this error:

```
Failed to load �߻, error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /home/.../dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6/libhostfxr.so failed
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370
```

Output of `ldd`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd03dfd000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fca18105000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fca180ea000)
        libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fca17f9b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fca17da9000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fca1834f000)
```

Also, I am running on Ubuntu 20.04. However, I followed the SDK installation instructions for 18.04, as (at the time) there was no instructions for 20.04.

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: I read the article, but my Linux executable still doesn't run. Should I try running in a CLI?

Comment: Can you debug it in VSCode?

Comment: I get this error when running from terminal:
`Failed to load �߻, error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /home/austin/dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6/libhostfxr.so failed
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370`
I followed the link and it didn't help.

Comment: When debugging:
`Cannot create .NET debug configurations. The OmniSharp server is still initializing or has exited unexpectedly.`

Comment: I don't know, but add that additional information to your question.  And change the title of your question to better reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Ok, I need you to run `ldd /home/austin/dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6/libhostfxr.so` and paste the output here. The issue is that the library couldn't find the standard library C that it's linking to. Also can you mention which Linux Distribution are you on?

Comment: Ok. I believe this more context might help you.

Comment: That is a very odd issue, because your library is already linking to libc and yet it is trying to link in musl libc as well. I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04 on VM and check into it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It was an installation misconfiguration problem.

To prevent an issue like this from arising again:

- Do not install the Snap version.
- Do not have conflicting binaries in your system. This confused my system a bit because I had installed from the package manager and also had an unzipped/configured binary in my home directory.

Comment: This is understandable, as you were testing a preview build which can mess up the machine. That's why so many people now use VSCode remote development with Docker containers, where recycling the containers to clean state is super easy.